# Why can't I see my shellcode executing in Immunity Debugger?

Tags: windows, debugging, exploit, shellcode

I am doing an exercise on creating custom shellcode (windows). The goal is to create shellcode that will delete the firewall log file. I successfully spawned a reverse shell with metasploit, using a python program I wrote, but when I try writing my own shellcode I am not successful yet. It's partly because Immunity is behaving in a strange way:

Reaching a certain point in the execution, Immunity exits. Yet when I press pause and step into again, I can see my filepath string in ebx. So my shellcode was executed, but I can't see the instructions being executed.

If you can help with immunity's behavior I would appreciate it...

[image]

[image: shellcode executed]

Comment: Please do not use [screenshots of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: well, give us more to work on. Your shellcode, instructions on how to get it injected and to what? From what you provided you have an exception of access violation and you need to fix it. But why you have it (i.e. what's wrong) it's hard to tell.